# how do I improve my regex (which isn't working )

Tags: java, regex

My target strings look like these `somecrap +num3.whatever-something`.
I would like to find all the substrings of the form `NUM<SOMENUMBER><DOT><WHATEVER>`

(Caveat : I would not want to match strings that look like this: `whatever.num3.whatever`)

**Note:** I would like to be able to retrieve the number and the start index of the substring (ie., by doing `myMatcher.group(1)` and `myMatcher.start()`, respectively).

So I tried this regex `\\bnum(\\d*)(?=\\.)`, but that would match `foo.num3.bar`.

So I changed it to `[^\\.]\\bnum(\\d*)(?=\\.)` hoping it would exclude all the strings where `num` is prefixed with a dot, but then `myMatcher.start()` on `"+(num3.bar)"`would give me the index of the left-paren `(` (and not the `n`). (because `PAREN == NOT DOT` )

So could you please tell me how to fix my regex?

Comment: If `num` has to be at the beginning of the string, use `^` (instead of `\\b`).

Comment: You said string must start with `num`, then why are you matching `.` before `num`?

Comment: When you say "the start index of the substring", what substring are you talking about?  If you mean the one starting with `num`, then wouldn't that always be 0 since you want `num` to be at the beginning of the string?

Comment: No, I didn't mean "num" has to be the beginning of a string. (That would have been toooo easy!)

Comment: Updated the question. SOrry for the confusion.

Comment: You want this to match - `abcnum3.asdf`?

Comment: No. That should NOT match.

Comment: Is there a `+` in your strings as well? Can you post a couple of example strings? This should be straight forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match pattern - `num3.whatever` not preceded by a *dot* or any other alphabet, then you can use *negative look-behind:*

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<![.a-zA-Z])num(\\d)\\..*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("+(num3.bar)");

if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.start() + " : " + matcher.group(1));
}
```

Comment: Ah, that seems to work! (haven't tested all the cases, but +1 for you. Thank yoU!!!)

Answer (score 1):

Use this lookbehind `(?<=\\s|^)` in your regex instead of `\\b`. It means preceded by white space, or at the start of the string. This way it will not pick the `num` from the middle of any non-white string.